# Using sqlite with Laravel 4

Tags: sqlite, laravel, laravel-4

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but in my `app/config/database.php` file I've changed the default driver to sqlite.

First off I got this error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database (SQL: create table "migrations" ("migration" varchar null, "batch" integer null)) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

So I made `app/database/production.sqlite` writable.

Now I get this error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file (SQL: create table "migrations" ("migration" varchar null, "batch" integer null)) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to put the sqlite file in `app/storage` which is already writeable?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the folder that holds the db-file? Must be writeable.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, and got around it by running the `migrate` command using the owner of the current file, like so:

```
sudo -u username php artisan migrate
```

So, as Rob Gordijn suggested, this is a permissions related issue.